# How to select checkbox at kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want add checkbox at kendo grid.I found this example http://jsbin.com/uzinij/3/edit?html,js,output.But I am using different version of kendo grid.I add newer version of kedno ui and jquery.But now it is not working.I am not expert in jqery.http://jsbin.com/vawahesige/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`live` is deprecated in the new version of jQuery so you should change it by `on`.

Change where you have:

```
$('.check_row').live('click', function (e) {
    ...
});

$("#checkAll").live('click', function (e) {
    ...
});
```

by:

```
$('#grid').on('click', '.check_row', function (e) {
    ...
});

$("#grid").on('click', '#checkAll', function (e) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.It worked.But when i check a row then sometime it checked all row.Any idea.Thanks @OnaBai

Comment: That's something about the logic of the code, doesn't have to do with jQuery version and also happens with the original post that you mention in the original question.